# Error uploading bot to Teams

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, office-store

I'm having some problems to upload the .zip file to microsoft Teams in my machine. When I go to bots tabs and I add the bot using "sideload a bot or a tab" button I'm having this error
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eorly.png)

I closed and opened Teams but still the same problem

Here you have the manifest example:

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.0",
    "id": "{app-id}",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "packageName": "{app-name}",
    "developer": {
        "name": "{name}",
        "websiteUrl": "{url}",
        "privacyUrl": "{url}",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "{url}"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "{name}"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "{description}",
        "full": "{description}"
    },
    "accentColor": "#38a9f6", 
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "app-id",
            "scopes": [ "team", "personal" ]
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "color": "{logo_name}",
        "outline": "{logo_name}"
    },
    "permissions": ["identity"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that apparently microsoft has a bug in the platform processing the length of the "description field", if this field is more than 250 characters it's returning that error. The solution is short the description in the manifest file because the bot will take the description that appear in the microsoft seller dashboard. They'll fix this.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it appears as if you have not enabled the Public Developer Preview.  This is the best way to ensure your v1.0 manifest will successfully load with all the features documented on MSDN.  [Here's how to enable Public Developer Preview.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/publicpreview)

In addition, the actual values you place in the manifest may cause issues.  Assuming you replace all the fields with actual values (e.g. actual GUID and Bot IDs, proper icons that conform to the specs as listed in the [Packaging guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage)), your format appears to be fine.  Happy to review your real manifest though.